# Implement a queue of a 3X3 Matrix

Tags: java, arraylist, queue

Basically, I am trying to Implement a queue of object
Consider 3x3 matrix will input by the user and then Next we will push more matrix on there. The queue will look like below.

1 2 3     2 3 4    1 2 3

4 5 6     5 6 7    7 8 0

7 8 9     1 0 8    4 5 6

if we pop

2 3 4     1 2 3

5 6 7     7 8 0

1 0 8     4 5 6

I manage to create a matrix but cannot manage to push on queue

```
import java.util.*;


public class Matrix {
    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        int [][]arr = new int[3][3];
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i,j;
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        
        ArrayList<Integer> row1 = new ArrayList<>();
        for(i=0;i<3;i++) {
                row1.add(sc.nextInt());
                
        }
        list.add(row1);
        
        ArrayList<Integer> row2 = new ArrayList<>();
        for(i=0;i<3;i++) {
            row2.add(sc.nextInt());
            
    }
        list.add(row2);
        
        ArrayList<Integer> row3 = new ArrayList<>();
        for(i=0;i<3;i++) {
            row3.add(sc.nextInt());
            
    }
        list.add(row3);
        
        //for display
        for(i=0;i<list.size();i++) {
                System.out.println(list.get(i)+" ");
            
            
        }
        
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't see you define a queue. What have you tried?

Comment: I don't understand what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let's see if I can provide a little help. First, in your code, you define int[][] arr, but you don't use it. So I'd get rid of that.

Queue is another container class, like ArrayList, which you're already using. So what you need to do is define:

```
Queue<ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>> myQueue = new Queue<ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>>();
```

You can then add to it:

```
myQueue.add(list);
```

However, I don't know why your assignment is to do this, so I'm not sure if I'm leading you down the proper path.